# i extend class want exten contructor laravel. php

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

i extend class want exten contructor  laravel. php i extend class want exten contructor  laravel.
i extend class want exten contructor  laravel.
contructor class children

```
function __construct($documentTemplate) {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Contructor class parent...i extend class want exten contructor  laravel.....i extend class want exten contructor  laravel....i extend class want exten contructor  laravel.

```
 public function __construct($documentTemplate)
    {
        // Temporary document filename initialization
        $this->tempDocumentFilename = tempnam(Settings::getTempDir(), 'PhpWord');
        if (false === $this->tempDocumentFilename) {
            throw new CreateTemporaryFileException(); // @codeCoverageIgnore
        }

        // Template file cloning
        if (false === copy($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename)) {
            throw new CopyFileException($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename); // @codeCoverageIgnore
        }

        // Temporary document content extraction
        $this->zipClass = new ZipArchive();
        $this->zipClass->open($this->tempDocumentFilename);
        $index = 1;
        while (false !== $this->zipClass->locateName($this->getHeaderName($index))) {
            $this->tempDocumentHeaders[$index] = $this->readPartWithRels($this->getHeaderName($index));
            $index++;
        }
        $index = 1;
        while (false !== $this->zipClass->locateName($this->getFooterName($index))) {
            $this->tempDocumentFooters[$index] = $this->readPartWithRels($this->getFooterName($index));
            $index++;
        }

        $this->tempDocumentMainPart = $this->readPartWithRels($this->getMainPartName());
        $this->tempDocumentSettingsPart = $this->readPartWithRels($this->getSettingsPartName());
        $this->tempDocumentContentTypes = $this->zipClass->getFromName($this->getDocumentContentTypesName());
    }
```

[See screenshot for error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFR2E.png)

Comment: If the question editor asks you to write more text, it means _provide more information_, not copy-and-paste the same (unclear) thing multiple times! Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the param to `parent::__construct();` in your extend class.

So that:

```
function __construct($documentTemplate) {
    parent::__construct($documentTemplate);
}
```